# How obtain an Data Dependence Graph (DDG) with LLVM?

Tags: llvm

It seems LLVM can now emit DDGs for each loop in a function (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-12.0.1/llvm/lib/Analysis/DDGPrinter.cpp).

I am able to generate CFG and Callgraph with `opt --dot-cfg foo.bc` and with `opt --dot-callgraph foo.bc`, but the similar `opt --dot-ddg-only foo.bc` executes but generates no `.dot` file. I also tried `opt -passes=dot-ddg foo.bc` without success.

Is there another `opt` possible call? Or someone has suggestions for other similar tools?

C code used (`foo.bc` obtained with `clang -c -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.bc`):

```
void foo(int b[], int c[], int n){
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    b[i] = c[i] + b[i-1];
  }
}

int main(){
  int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int c[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    
  foo(b, c, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer is probably naive as i am not an expert. I came across the same problem and found out this. First i compile your program to a readable IR:

1. `clang -c -S -emit-llvm foo.c -o foo.ll` . Notice this is equivalent to a O0 optimisation level.
2. the `-debug-pass-manager` option has been key to me to understand why nothing was neither printed nor written out. Call

   ```
   % opt foo.ll -passes=dot-ddg -debug-pass-manager
   ```

   (*Note:* this is using the new pass manager syntax)
   I noticed in the output, things like:

   ```
   Skipping pass DDGDotPrinterPass on foo due to optnone attribute
   ```
3. Edit the IR `foo.ll` and indeed, we can spot the `optnone` attribute, e.g:

   ```
    ; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
    define dso_local void @foo(i32* noundef %b, i32* noundef %c, i32 noundef %n) #0 {
   ```
4. You can disable this attribute. I regenerate the IR with the proper option `-disable-O0-optnone`

   ```
   % clang -O0 -Xclang -disable-O0-optnone foo.c -emit-llvm -S -o foo.ll
   ```

   and now the attribute is gone :

   ```
   ; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind uwtable
   define dso_local void @foo(i32* noundef %b, i32* noundef %c, i32 noundef %n) #0 {
   ```
5. This time the pass will take effect:

   ```
   % opt foo.ll -disable-output  -passes=dot-ddg
   Writing 'ddg.foo.for.cond.dot'
   ```
6. Final result, that i can't decipher yet, is: [image: dot file generated]